# How to avoid multiple azure B2C user session

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to avoid multiple user sessions AD B2C de azure.
I am using B2C to login in a Xamarin App and in turn to authenticate an Azure function, I would like to know if it is possible to prevent a user from starting multiple sessions on different devices. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the built-in policies or the custom policies? this might help others in providing an option for you.

Comment: Hi @Ivanrlg. Do you mean that you don't want the same user to be able to sign on to different devices into the same app at once?

Comment: Hello, I'm using built-in policies @IzzulHaziq

Comment: Exactly, I would like a user to be able to login only once, or in the best case I can control the maximum number of active sessions he may have. @ChrisPadgett

Comment: Any updates on this? We are facing the same problem and we don't know how to restrict the user on using the app only on one device at a time